# ¿Cómo resolver el error openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory) en Pandoc con Ubuntu 18?

Tags: ubuntu, docx, pandoc

En el pasado yo podía convertir sin ningún problema archivos con extensión `.docx` (descargados desde Google Drive) a archivos con extensión `.tex`, usando este comando:

```
pandoc -s elArchivoLocal.docx -o elArchivoLocal.tex
```

Pero desde la semana pasada esto no es posible. Cuando ejecuto el comando obtengo el siguiente error:

> pandoc: elArchivoLocal.docx: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such
> file or directory)

En algunos foros he leído soluciones como poner la ruta absoluta, cosa que he hecho:

```
pandoc -s home/miusuario/Descargas/elArchivoLocal.docx -o home/miusuario/Descargas/elArchivoLocal.tex
```

Pero el error persiste:

> pandoc: home/miusuario/Descargas/elArchivoLocal.docx: openBinaryFile:
> does not exist (No such file or directory)

Como decía al principio, esto me funciona hasta hace un par de semanas, he convertido muchos archivos `docx` a `.tex` con este comando. Además, otros tipos de conversiones (desde una página web por ejemplo) funcionan sin problemas. El problema es con los archivos `.docx`.

¿Cómo podría hacer que funcione de nuevo?

Esta es mi versión de pandoc:

```
pandoc 1.19.2.4
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.5, texmath 0.9.4.4, skylighting 0.3.3.1
Default user data directory: /home/miusuario/.pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2016 John MacFarlane
Web:  http://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is no warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness
for a particular purpose.
```

Y mi sistema operativo es `Ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: por las dudas, la dirección absoluta debería ser `/home/...` y no `home/..`. También no estaría de más probar `pandoc -s ./elArchivoLocal.docx ..`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho el error era una tontería. En el archivo que estaba tratando de convertir había una palabra que en castellano normal iría acentuada, pero yo no uso acentos para nombres de archivo. Al escribir el comando el nombre del archivo se escribió con acento y por eso no estaba funcionando.